# How to use Swift non-NSObject subclass in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I'm experiencing some issues to use Swift in my Objective-C project.

I use the following lib for example (https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper). I've tried the thing to add @objc directive before my subclass but it's say that only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc. Seems it's related only to Swift 2.0

So my question is, how I can use pure swift classes or libraries in my Objective-C projet ? If it's stil possible ...

My model looks like this:
    import Foundation
    import ObjectMapper

```
class SSStreetAddressRequest: Mappable {

    var street:String?
    var city:String?
    var state:String?
    var zip:String?

    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        street  <- map["street"]
        city    <- map["city"]
        state   <- map["state"]
        zip     <- map["zip"]
    }
}
```

Mappable is a protocol:
https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/blob/master/ObjectMapper/Core/Mapper.swift

Answer (score 5):

In Objective-C you cannot create a class without a superclass. Thats why the @objc will not work without at least NSObject.

So you have to use at least NSObject.
Thats how i would do it

```
@objc class SSStreetAddressRequest: NSObject {
    var street:String?
    var city:String?
    var state:String?
    var zip:String?
}

extension SSStreetAddressRequest : Mappable {
    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }

    @objc func mapping(map: Map) {
        street  <- map["street"]
        city    <- map["city"]
        state   <- map["state"]
        zip     <- map["zip"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't change the problem because Map is not exposed to objective-c (parameter of this method)

@objc func mapping(map: Map) {

Seems really a pain to deal with pure swift and Obj-c

Comment: your protocoll decalartion of Mappable should also decalre @objc.

Comment: Yes I know the fact it's that a third-part library (ObjectMapper)

Comment: ohh ... thats bad. Hmm, currently i started working with use_frameworks! for cocoapods. This will privide better usage for swift and objc i think. Try to import the third party libary as a framework. But iam not sure if this will work,

Comment: If you want to use a very cool object mapper than use Mantle :) this one is awsome and Objective c. It will also take care of NSCopying

Comment: Ok thanks for these tips, but I would begin to make all new things in my project to be build with Swift but it's gonna wrong.. At the end I will keep with Objective-c for this project I guess

Comment: "In Objective-C you cannot create a class without a superclass." This is not true. In Objective-C, you *can* create a class without a superclass.

Comment: then tell me how please. Would be interesting.

Comment: @user102008 thx for the comment, so that means, that he has to implement the basic methods to have a root class working on objective-c and it will work?