# Only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc

Tags: swift, linux

I have to set value to property by string name representation.

```
import Foundation

@objc class A:NSObject {
    var x:String = ""
}

var a = A()
a.x = "ddd"

print(a.x)

a.setValue("zzz", forKey:"x")

print(a.x)
```

And getting strange errors during compilation:

```
main.swift:4:2: error: only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc

@objc class A:NSObject {

~^~~~~

main.swift:13:1: error: value of type 'A' has no member 'setValue'

a.setValue("zzz", forKey:"x")

^ ~~~~~~~~
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

PS: reproducible on Swift 4.0 & 3.1.1 (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS)

Edited:

```
import Foundation

@objc class A:NSObject {
   @objc dynamic  var x:String = ""
}

var a = A()
a.x = "ddd"

print(a.x)

a.setValue("zzz", forKeyPath:"x")

print(a.x)
```

Output:

error: only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc
@objc class A:NSObject {

error: property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C
   @objc dynamic  var x:String = ""

note: Swift structs cannot be represented in Objective-C
   @objc dynamic  var x:String = ""

error: value of type 'A' has no member 'setValue'
a.setValue("zzz", forKeyPath:"x")

EDIT 2:
Just trying like "c-style":

```
func set<T>(_ val:T, forKey key:String) {
    print("SET:\(self) \(key) to \(val)")
    let ivar: Ivar = class_getInstanceVariable(type(of: self), key)!
    let pointerToInstanceField:UnsafeMutableRawPointer = Unmanaged.passRetained(self).toOpaque().advanced(by: ivar_getOffset(ivar))
    let pointer = pointerToInstanceField.assumingMemoryBound(to: T.self)
    pointer.pointee = val
}
```

It works well, but causes bad access in the recursive calls. Probably some retain/release issues. Will dig dipper. Also does not work on Linux (as mentioned in answers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Swift non-NSObject subclass in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997550/how-to-use-swift-non-nsobject-subclass-in-objective-c)

Comment: It's a misleading error (which you may well want to file a bug over). The problem is simply that there is no Obj-C runtime with Swift on Linux. You cannot mark something `@objc`, and you cannot use KVC (consider using Swift key paths instead).

Comment: @Hamish, thank you for suggestion. Could you point me for some docs about Swift key paths? Cant google anything about. Also it requires (at)objc suffixes as well. Am I right?

Comment: @jww, my question is not duplication of your suggestion

Comment: @NickZaporozhchenko Swift key paths themselves don't require Obj-C exposure; you can read more about them on [the evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md) (there's also lots of online resources that you can find with a simple search for "Swift 4 keypath").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Documentation**

> Swift without the Objective-C Runtime: Swift on Linux does not depend
>   on the Objective-C runtime nor includes it. While Swift was designed
>   to interoperate closely with Objective-C when it is present, it was
>   also designed to work in environments where the Objective-C runtime
>   does not exist.

https://swift.org/blog/swift-linux-port/

Which is clear, provided that it states:

> value of type 'A' has no member 'setValue'

It basically tells that there is no KVC mechanism underneath. `setValue` method comes from Objective-C runtime, which is absent on Linux. Thus, it's a no-go and what you're trying to accomplish is simply not possible.

Other than that, the following rule is applied on systems with Obj-C runtime environment:

---

[Key-Value Coding with Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html)

> Swift objects that inherit from NSObject or one of its subclasses are
>   key-value coding compliant for their properties by default. Whereas in
>   Objective-C, a property’s accessors and instance variables must follow
>   certain patterns, a standard property declaration in Swift
>   automatically guarantees this. On the other hand, many of the
>   protocol’s features are either not relevant or are better handled
>   using native Swift constructs or techniques that do not exist in
>   Objective-C. For example, because all Swift properties are objects,
>   you never exercise the default implementation’s special handling of
>   non-object properties.

Also: [Requiring Dynamic Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID57)

> Swift APIs that are callable from Objective-C must be available
>   through dynamic dispatch. However, the availability of dynamic
>   dispatch doesn’t prevent the Swift compiler from selecting a more
>   efficient dispatch approach when those APIs are called from Swift
>   code.
>
> You use the @objc attribute along with the dynamic modifier to require
>   that access to members be dynamically dispatched through the
>   Objective-C runtime. Requiring this kind of dynamic dispatch is rarely
>   necessary. However, it is necessary when using APIs like key–value
>   observing or the method_exchangeImplementations function in the
>   Objective-C runtime, which dynamically replace the implementation of a
>   method at runtime.
>
> Declarations marked with the dynamic modifier must also be explicitly
>   marked with the @objc attribute unless the @objc attribute is
>   implicitly added by the declaration’s context. For information about
>   when the @objc attribute is implicitly added, see Declaration
>   Attributes in The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4).

---

Elements must also be declared dynamic in order to be KVO-compatible (for KVC, inheriting from `NSObject` is enough):

```
@objc dynamic var x:String = ""
```

If `String` doesn't work out, then try going with `NSString`.

If neither helps, this seems to be a Linux-specific issue, which doesn't appear to support KVC/KVO mechanism (which is also understandable).

P.S. With the code provided, your issue reproduced in Xcode on Mac, too.

Comment: Just tried - no success. also added new errors: 1: property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C; 2: Swift structs cannot be represented in Objective-C

Comment: Try defining it as `NSString`

Comment: Other than that, it's a bit surprising. `The String type bridges with the Objective-C class NSString and offers interoperability with C functions that works with strings.`

Comment: @NickZaporozhchenko Note that *KVC* doesn't require `dynamic`; only KVO.

Comment: @Hexfire `@objc` is still required for KVC though :) It needs to be exposed to the Obj-C runtime (so that it can be seen by `setValue(_:forKeyPath:)`), but Swift itself doesn't need to use message dispatch to call the property's accessors.

Comment: @Hamish yeah, I'm aware of that. But your notes are spot on. :)